# How do i goto next frame after drop all the objects - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i tried to search this but didn't find the right answer.

i have this script of drag and drop game.
and am looking the way it to go to next frame after droping all the objects into the target

help.

```js
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;

blue.buttonMode = true;
blue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
blue.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);       

red.buttonMode = true;
red.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
red.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);   

green.buttonMode = true;
green.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
green.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);   

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 event.target.startDrag();
 event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
 objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
 objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 event.target.stopDrag();
 var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
 var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
 if(event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget)
 {
  event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
  event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
  event.target.buttonMode = false;
  event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
  event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
 }
 else
 {
  event.target.x = objectoriginalX;
  event.target.y = objectoriginalY;
 }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? The correct drop is the second **{...}** block from below. The **gotoAndStop(...)** command is to move playhead to another frame. All you probably need is to count how many objects were dropped correctly and do the thing on count 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too certain what you mean by 'next Frame' but you could surely do this with a simple
counter.
Add a class variable:

```
private var counter:int=0;
```

As I can see from your code, you have 3 objects (red, green blue) - now simply increment the
counter variable each time you successfully dropped an object. If it reached a certain amount
(2 in this case), 'go to the next frame'.

```
if(event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget)
    {
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
        event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
        counter++;
        if(counter==2)
        {
            // go to next frame
        }
    }
```